# Use Method of generic type

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I am currently writing an XML converter for a supply chain project. We use Requests and Orders.

The converter has multiple method that currently do same but are separately implements for requests and orders.

I have therefore created an abstract class to improve maintainability of the code and used a generic type:

```
public abstract class AbstractConverter<T extends BusinessObject>
```

Then I have the specific implementations for the actual converters

```
public class OrderConverter extends AbstractConverter<Order>
public class RequestConverter extends AbstractConverter<Request>
```

As I said, I have several methods in the two specific classes that basically do the same, so I naturally want them in the abstract class. I have now added the following method to the abstract class:

```
protected Comment createComment(T obj) {
    String remark;
    if (obj instanceof Order) {
        remark = ((Order) obj).getRemark();
    } else if (obj instanceof Request) {
        remark = ((Request) obj).getRequestRemark();
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("This method does not support objects of the type " + obj.getClass().toString());
    }
    return new Comment(remark);
}
```

My question now is: is this the way to go or is there a more elegant way to use generics in this context?

I need this solved but I also want to use good style.

Comment: What does "basically" mean? There is no "a little bit pregnant". They are the same, then pull them into the abstract class or they are not, then implement them separately (see wero's answer). Increasing complexity and UNmaintainability by introducing if/else/instanceof blocks is IMHO really a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The natural object oriented solution is to make `createComment` an abstract method

```
protected abstract Comment createComment(T obj);
```

and let the subclasses implement it:

```
public class OrderConverter extends AbstractConverter<Order> {
     protected Comment createComment(Order order) {
           return new Comment(order.getRemark());
     }
}

public class RequestConverter extends AbstractConverter<Request> {
     protected Comment createComment(Request request) {
           return new Comment(request.getRequestRemark());
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest extracting the `getRemark` method to an interface which both `Request` and `Order` implements.

That way you can simply check if the incoming generic object is an instance of the interface.

```
protected Comment createComment(T obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Remarkable) {
        return new Comment(((Remarkable) obj).getRemark());
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("This method does not support objects of the type " + obj.getClass().toString());
}
```

Comment: ... and you can even skip that `instanceof` if it is possible to have `BusinessObject` also implement that `Remarkable` interface.

Comment: @DaDaDom then there's no use in having an interface. If all `BusinessObject` can return remarks, just use an abstract method in that class.

Comment: Thanks for this input. Unfortunately I cannot do this, as I cannot change the Order and Request Classes as this would mean a very large refactorinf of existing code.

Comment: The question is also more a general one, as I have a few dozen methods that are currently implemented twice and I don't see the point of having two separate implementation if the code does basucally the same

Comment: @Fish-Guts That sounds like bad coding. You even admitted wanting to have more elegant code. I'd extract all methods that are "almost" duplicated either into interfaces, or if applicable, into the abstract class directly. It drastically improves readability, and usefullness of your objects.